# How to execute .py file through python shell..?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using IDLE GUI
I created a file called *doss.py* and it is saved in C:\python34

now on IDLE (GUI)

i want that doss.py to open without any RUN command. 
in python27 i used

```
>>> import doss.py
```

it worked very fine

bt idk why its showing some LOC in red color.

its :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    import doss.py
ImportError: No module named 'doss.py'; 'doss' is not a package
```

Comment: "import doss" instead of "import doss.py"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a module called `doss.py`. Your module, if stored in a file named `doss.py`, is named `doss`. So try `import doss`.

`doss.py` would be a submodule of `doss` named `py`.

Comment: I created 1 more file called boy.py,

>>import boy
Hello

my code execute but again am trying to run the same code its not executing.. moreover whats the problem in doss.py

i just gave the name doss.py

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that `import doss.py` would **not** have worked in Python 2.7's standard shell, at least not in the way that you think. Simply put, `import`-ing a module is not equivalent to running it from the command line, except inadvertently in some cases. Also, no version of Python has ever accept filenames (e.g. `doss.py`) as the arguments to `import`; it has always been a package name (which might be `doss` if there's a file called `doss.py` in the current directory, but [it gets more complicated](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)).

The standard Python interactive shell has never included a mechanism to do quite what you want: to load and execute a Python script roughly as if from the command line.

You may want to try the enhanced [IPython shell](http://ipython.org) instead. IPython does have a [`%run` command that does what you want](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#running-and-editing), in addition to a number of other enhancements.

Comment: My mistake , i tried 

>>> import hello

but why import doss is the error ?

the above script am getting when i execute 
>>> import doss

Comment: Take a look at the "more complicated" link in my answer above; what `import` does is rather subtle and intricate. If you simply want to run scripts like from the command line, `import` is **not** what you want; use IPython's `%run` or just run them from the command line.